# Running geospatial queries in PySpark in Databricks

Tags: pyspark, databricks, geospatial, azure-databricks

I have PySpark dataframes with couple of columns, on of them being gps location (in WKT format). What is the easiest way to pick only rows that are inside some polygon? Does it scale when there are ~1B rows?

I'm using Azure Databricks and if the solution exists in Python, that would be even better, but Scala and SQl are also fine.

Edit: Alex Ott's answer - Mosaic - works and I find it easy to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Databricks Labs includes the [project Mosaic](https://github.com/databrickslabs/mosaic/) that is a library for processing of the geospatial data. And it's heavily optimized for Databricks.

This library provides the `st_contains` & `st_intersects` ([doc](https://databrickslabs.github.io/mosaic/api/spatial-predicates.html#st-contains)) functions that could be used to find rows that are inside your polygons or other objects.  That functions are available in all available languages - Scala, SQL, Python, R.  For example, in SQL:

```sql
SELECT st_contains("POLYGON ((30 10, 40 40, 20 40, 10 20, 30 10))", 
                   "POINT (25 15)")
```

Answer (score 0):

openai says:

I think you can use `ST_Contains` function.
`import pyspark.sql.functions as F`

df.withColumn("is_inside", F.expr("ST_Contains(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0))'), gps)")).where("is_inside").show()

Comment: What do you mean by "openai says"? You're referring to Github Copilot's output? :)

Comment: `ST_Contains` should come from somewhere...